# Hibernate + Jersey + Jackson getting “org.hibernate.TransactionException: nested transactions not supported” randomly

Tags: java, web-services, hibernate, jersey, jackson

I have buit a Webservice using these technologies + c3p0 for database handling. It works ok most of the time but I have a 3-5% ratio (sometimes even a 10%) of failed acces due to this error.

I am using Hibernate this way:

-Session Factory

```
private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {           
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();        

        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
        return configuration
        .buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    //reabrimos la sesion si esta cerrada al liberar los recursos
    if(sessionFactory.isClosed())
    {
        System.out.println("Reopen session");
        sessionFactory.openSession();
    }

    return sessionFactory;
}
```

Then in my `hibernate.cfg.xml` I have the following line:

```
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

Finally in my endpoints I have defined a `hibernate_session` class which I use as follows:

```
@Path("/projects")
public class ProjectServiceImpl {

@Context
SecurityContext security;
Session hibernate_session = null;

@POST
@Path("sync.json")
@Produces(value = {"application/json",
        "application/vnd.myapp-v1+json",
        "application/vnd.myapp-v2+json"})
public Response syncProjects(
        @DefaultValue("") @FormParam("projects") String in_projects_str,
        @DefaultValue("0") @FormParam("last_sync") long last_sync,
        @Context Request request) {

   //...

   hibernate_session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()
            .getCurrentSession();

  if (hibernate_session == null) {
    ResponseMessage rm = new ResponseMessage();
        rm.setCode(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.getStatusCode());
        rm.setMessage("Hibernate Session is Null");
        rm.setType("ERROR");
        return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(rm)
                .type("application/json").build();
    }

    try {

        hibernate_session.beginTransaction();

        //Database work...

        hibernate_session.flush();

        hibernate_session.getTransaction().commit();

        }catch (RuntimeException | IllegalAccessException
                | InvocationTargetException e) {
            try {
                if (hibernate_session.getTransaction() != null) {
                    hibernate_session.getTransaction().rollback();
                }
            } catch (RuntimeException rbe) {
                System.err.println("Couldn’t roll back transaction");
            }

            e.printStackTrace();
            ResponseMessage rm = new ResponseMessage();
            rm.setCode(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.getStatusCode());
            rm.setMessage(e.getMessage());
            rm.setType("ERROR");
            return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(rm)
                    .type("application/json").build();

        }
    }

    return Response.ok().entity(result_entity)
            .type("application/json").build();
}
```

My `hibernate_session` is a class attribute, do I have to change it to a local variable?. As far as I know the end points will be executed in different threads so I have assumed that I am working with different instances of my endpoint container class and these class attributes will not get overriden by multiple request.

Any light you can shed on this topic will be appreciated,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check if you are not starting another transaction somewhere in the `//Database work...` part

Comment: Are there any class level annotations?

Comment: I have added class level annotations @stevedbrown

Comment: Maybe will a full stack trace we can better diagnose your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks all for your replies. I finally managed to solve the problem.

In one of my multiple entries there was a begin transaction (necessary to create criterias) but was not commited. The result was that a reused thread that had called that method before would throw a nested exception. By commiting the transaction the problem was solved :)

Answer (score 3):

You aren't using openSession and getCurrentSession properly.

```
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    //reabrimos la sesion si esta cerrada al liberar los recursos
    //change this: if(sessionFactory.isClosed()) to this:
    if(sessionFactory == null || sessionFactory.isClosed())
    {
        System.out.println("Reopen session"); // Really setup session factory
        //change this: sessionFactory.openSession(); to this:
        sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
    }

    return sessionFactory;
}
```

That's not the problem though, your code there just isn't doing what it's supposed to. You need to change:

```
hibernate_session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
```

to

```
hibernate_session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
```

As per the SessionFactory Javadoc:

> Obtains the current session. The definition of what exactly "current" means controlled by the CurrentSessionContext impl configured for use.

It's safe to assume your CurrentSessionContext is not thread safe.

Comment: AFAIK  `getCurrentSession()` returns you a valid session linked to the current thread as `hibernate.xml.cfg` says. But I will change it and give it a try. If I use `openSession()` i have to call `closeSession()` at the end of the method right?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you're seeing getCurrentSession() share your session - you could likely solve this problem more elegantly by using the annotation based Spring transaction manager. In that case, you don't need to worry about any of the transaction management, and getCurrentSession will work. If you use transaction scoped sessions then committing the transaction will close the session.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that a transaction is started, and before the transaction gets commited an attempt to start a new transaction is made.

This explains the error message that says that a nested transaction (the second transaction inside the ongoing transaction) is not supported.

This could be caused for example by incorrect error handling, for example starting a transaction, not catching an exception or catch and ignore and then try to begin a second transaction without having done either commit or rollback.

An idiom similar to this one should be used when doing programmatic transaction mananagement:

```
try {
    sess.getTransaction().begin();

    // do some work

    sess.getTransaction().commit()
}
catch (RuntimeException e) {
    sess.getTransaction().rollback();
    throw e;
}
```

Also important to bear mind is that after a rollback the session cannot be reused, as it's in an inconsistent state.

If using a framework like Spring, the use of the annotation `@Transactional` for declarative transaction management solves most of these problems for us and leads to more maintainable code, EJB3 has also similar functionality.

Comment: Thank you I am starting to see Spring. Do you know if the Threads from the users request are re-used? or every request has a new thread?

Comment: every request is bound from start to finish to only one thread, and in calls to the database the servlet thread blocks and then resumes until the completion of the request. at the end of the request depending on the container implementation the threads will go to a thread pool where they get reused in the next request, this is an optimization.